# Download Merchandise System

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hey Everyone my system is selling kits for each kit it compose of different products all of them are downloaded files. my problem is where would i place the products of each kit.

Sample KIT1 compose of game1, game2, game3, game4

PRODUCT TABLE

PRODUCTID: 1   SKU:   NAME:Kit100

where would I Place game1, game2, game3, game4

Comment: You will be more likely to get help if you make an attempt at solving the problem. Simply asking "How do I..." shows no effort on your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what you just said,

- You want a KIT table
- You want a PRODUCT table
- And to link them together, you need a KIT_ITEM or KIT_PRODUCT table to itemize the individual items/products within each Kit.

To be honest I'd name the top-level entity the customer buys (you called it a Kit) as a Product, and I'd name the parts as Components.

Products in normal business English, are individually purchasable.

You could also make a KIT_PRODUCT which is made up of 0..* "component" Products.

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction Mr Thomas as I am a asian.. :D english is our 2nd major language...

Comment: Yap KIT TABLE and PRODUCT table... so KIT link them to Product table via Kit_ITEM or Number and my games is in Product table ??

Comment: Yep, that's would be along the KIT -> PRODUCT lines you stated. Use KIT.ID to link them, either as a PRODUCT.FK_KIT (if each product belongs to only one Kit) or KIT_ITEM.FK_KIT using a join table (products can be included in more multiple kits).

Comment: Thank you so much for the Idea. Mr Thomas W